# Not able to alter column after renaming it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am first checking if column exist or not. If not then i rename existing column and then try to change its datatype. But when i run script i get error `Invalid column name Age`

```
if Not exists(select * from sys.columns 
        where Name = 'Age' and Object_ID = Object_ID('TestTable'))
begin

EXEC sp_RENAME 'TestTable.Name' , 'Age', 'COLUMN'

ALTER TABLE TestTable ALTER COLUMN Age int

Update TestTable set Age = 0

ALTER TABLE TestTable ALTER COLUMN Age int Not Null

end
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. By splitting your If condition with `Not Exists` and `exists`.

```
if Not exists(select * from sys.columns 
        where Name = 'Age' and Object_ID = Object_ID('TestTable'))
BEGIN

EXEC sp_RENAME 'TestTable.Name' , 'Age', 'COLUMN'
END
GO

if exists(select * from sys.columns 
        where Name = 'Age' and Object_ID = Object_ID('TestTable'))
begin
ALTER TABLE TestTable ALTER COLUMN Age int

Update TestTable set Age = 0

ALTER TABLE TestTable ALTER COLUMN Age int Not Null
END
GO
```

**Edit**:

---

About Batch in SQL from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175502(v=sql.105).aspx)

> A table cannot be changed and then the new columns referenced in the
>   same batch.

So, renaming and altering in the same batch not worked.

[See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712439(v=vs.85).aspx)

> When an error occurs while executing a batch of SQL statements,
>
> - No statements in the batch are executed.